# How to graceful shutdown gradle/ set java options for java app in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have two questions about [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) in Intellij IDEA

---

I know the [exit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmlYu.png) will gracefully shutdown java app.
(*File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Build and run using Intellij*)

But I wonder how to gracefully shutdown my java app via gradle run?

Because there is no the **exit button** when run by gradle.
(*File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Gradle -> Build and run using Gradle*)

---

Another question is how to set java options (like *-Xmx* option) to java app by [edit configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kyQw.png)?
The VM options seem set gradle VM option instead of my java app options.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Go to help -> Change Memory Settings
Make necessary changes then save file and restart intelij.

Refer below for detail
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/increasing-memory-heap.html

Comment: Thanks, actually I not only set memory but also dump file. Like **-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp**

Comment: For your first question: when you run any gradle task you will notice one small red button will appear beside edit configuration and also on the bottom left panel( if you have not minimised it). You can click that button to stop gradle task and that in turn will stop your java app.

Comment: Are you mean **stop button**?  I know, but it will not **gracefully shutdown** my java app. I wanna try **shutdown hook**.